# Problem in angular i18n generated xlf file for interpolation

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-library

I have an angular 11 library which supports i18n for translation. and used it in my angular 11 app. But when I generate xlf file using

`ng extract-i18n --output-path=src/locales/`

the generated file have problem in translation unit which contains interpolation.

to be precise: the translations which are coming from libraries and contains interpolation, have this problem

see the example below:

```html
<div i18n>there is some {{value}} and after that {{value1}}</div>
```

and the uint is like below

```xml
<source>there is some <x id="INTERPOLATION"/> and after that <x id="INTERPOLATION_1"/></source>
```

as you can see there is no "equiv-text"

and another example:

```html
<span i18n >The number should be greater than {{control.errors.min.min}}</span>
```

the unit is like below

```xml
<trans-unit id="d122272d37d6159fdb10fef947fc727a4a68b536" datatype="html">
  <source>The number should be greater than <x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="ey: string]: st"/></source>
  <context-group purpose="location">
    <context context-type="sourcefile">node_modules/projects/rira-utils/src/lib/form-element-error/form-element-error.component.ts</context>
    <context context-type="linenumber">34,40</context>
  </context-group>
</trans-unit>
```

and in the second example the equiv-text is some thing unrelated!!

PS:
If i build my library without `--prod` the problem is resolved. But it not recommended by angular.
And even if id build my own library this way. what can i do about other libraries
PS 2:
It happens just in version 11. I tested there was no problem with same scenario in version 10 of angular

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41034